# c/c++ assign RGBQUAD array to a bitmap

Tags: c++, c, screenshot

i am doing a program where you take a screenshot of a window and then scan every pixel of that picture. But I have a problem assigning RGBQUAD array to the taken screen. Every pixel has the same RGB which is 205. Here is a piece of my code:

```
RGBQUAD *pixel = malloc((ssWidth * ssHeight)* sizeof(RGBQUAD));
hdcScreen = GetDC(gameHandle);
hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, ssWidth, ssHeight);
SelectObject(hdc, hBmp);

BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, ssWidth, ssHeight, hdcScreen, xCenter, yCenter, SRCCOPY);

GetDIBits(hdc, hBmp, 0, ssHeight, pixel, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

int p = -1;

for(y_var = 0; y_var < ssWidth; y_var++)
{
    for(x_var = 0; x_var < ssHeight; x_var++)
    {
        if(ComparePixel(&pixel[++p]))
        {
            SetCursorPos(xCenter + x_var + 3, yCenter + y_var + 3);
        }
    }
}

bool ComparePixel(RGBQUAD *pixel)
{
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n"; pixel -> rgbRed, pixel -> rgbGreen, pixel -> rgbBlue);
    return false;
}
```

ComparePixel(RGBQUAD *pixel) function just checks the RGB values. How do i assign the RGBQUAD to the bitmap of the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues.

1. The `RGBQUAD **pixel = malloc(...` and `free(*pixel)` appear to be the problem.  I think you want `RGBQUAD *pixel = malloc((ssWidth * ssHeight)* sizeof(RGBQUAD));` (only 1 `*`)
2. Suspect the `pixels` in `GetDIBits()` s/b `pixel`.
3. I think you want `y_var = 0;` (x_var = 0; also)
4. `ComparePixel()` is not defined, but I think you want something closer to `if(ComparePixel(pixel[x_var+(y_var*ssWidth)], the_pixel_to_compare_against))`
5. The `free(*pixel);` s/b _after the 2 for loops and should be `free(pixel)`;

Comment: ok, despite the mistakes, i still don't get the result. The function `ComparePixel(RGBQUAD *pixel)` returns true if pixels match. However the RGBQUAD is either mixed up, because it gives me kind of mixed pixels, but colors match, or the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Please provide more info on function `ComparePixel()` including its declaration.  Your usage appears to only give it 1 pixel - so what is it comparing that pizel to?  Is `ComparePixel()` your code?, a library function?

Comment: i have edited the code. ComparePixel for now just prints the RGB of the current pixel.

Comment: 1. It looks better now, what is some of your `printf` output?  2: Question "GetDIBits and loop through pixels using X, Y" may provide needed info.  3. if ssWidth is not a multiple of 4, you may have RGBQAUD alignment issues. 4. Your RGB is `205`, maybe your .bmp file is 1-byte index/pixel format (256 color).  Be sure it is a 24-bit/pixel format.

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed it. I had to remove the `bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = 0`. Thanks for the additional help.